# Помогите создать корзину

Tags: aiogram, sqlite3

Есть задача, бот через которого можно заказывать пиццу, на выбор есть 4 пиццы, к каждой из пицц выбор размера, 15, 30см. После выбора пиццы и размера выходит инлайн клавиатура с кнопкой сохранить, по нажатию этой кнопки выбранная пицца с выбранным размером должны быть помещены в корзину для будующей оплаты, как сделать помещение в корзину. Знаю что нужна база данных sqlite3. Суть сохранять позиции в корзине

Answer (score 1):

Я, может быть, не очень понял ваш вопрос. Но алгоритм такой:

- Создать таблицу "cart" в базе данных sqlite3 со следующими столбцами: "id" (уникальный идентификатор), "название пиццы", "размер", "цена".
- При нажатии кнопки "сохранить" выбранная пицца и размер добавляются в таблицу "cart" как новая запись.
- Для получения информации о корзине можно использовать SQL-запрос "SELECT * FROM cart".
- Для удаления позиции из корзины можно использовать SQL-запрос "DELETE FROM cart WHERE id = <указанный id>"
- После оплаты, информация о корзине может быть удалена или сохранена для истории заказов.

Comment: ну алгоритм мне ясен) спасибо. мне не понятна реализация, как мне записывать значение в табл при нажатии инлайн кнопки?

Comment: ну я могу сказать, что нужно сделать INSERT INTO операцию... вы задайте хотя бы новый вопрос, опишите детально что у вас есть, приведите код хотя бы. спросите конкретно как сделать так, чтобы при вызове вот этой функции добавить что-то. нужны детали